# Running Xamarin app in appetize.io gives "Error installing app"

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

We are using appetize.io and now have problems with a Xamarin.Forms app. We zip the app bundle dir and upload it without problems.

But when we try to start the app we get the error message "Error installing app" and nothing else.

It does not help to turn on "debug log" - no output is produced. We suspect that is because the log is for output to the console, i.e. output produced by the app, and the app is not even installed.

Any pointers?

Comment: Errors like these usually mean that the device you are trying to use is not in the provisioning profile. Ensure that you got the Device ID in there, that profile is used for the build and try again.

Comment: As @GeraldVersluis mentioned, it's probably because of a missing Device ID. It could also be because of a missing entitlements file.

Comment: Appetize.io runs the app in a simulator and not on a device. Simulator builds are not signed as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem: When doing a "build all" from Xamarin, the produced iOS app bundle does not contain everything necessary to install and run in the simulator.

But if we run the app on the simulator from within Xamarin ("Start Debugging" in the menu), then the app dir in bin/iPhoneSimulator/Release suddenly grows a great deal and now contains all necessary files.

So in conclusion: Do not just do a "build all" or "rebuild all" from Xamarin. Do a "run" on the simulator and *then* zip and upload the app dir to appetize.io.